# Is it possible to produce an epoxide from 2-bromoacetyl bromide using methyl magnesium bromide

Tags: grignard-reagent, c-c-addition

This is also one of the questions from practice papers for the JEE , asks for 2 step reaction for epoxidation of ketene
[image: Text]

For product **A** , π complex is generated on c-c bond since carbon labelled 1 is electron deficient(inductive effect of sp carbon C2 and oxygen)

[image: Text]

**Is it possible to produce an epoxide from 2-bromoacetyl bromide using methyl magnesium bromide**

Comment: Suppose you generated the epoxide. Notice, very importantly, that the question's author bothered to stipulate _2 equivalents_ of the Grignard reagent. Why do you think that is?

Comment: Probably 1st equivalent to substitute methyl at acyl position and 2nd equivalent to make addition reaction on  carbonyl ---- but this gives me bromohydrin which is wrong

Comment: See first comment. "Suppose you generated the epoxide."

Comment: How stable is the bromohydrin alkoxide? Can it react further?

Comment: Since no-one has been back to wrap this up here is how is goes: The addition of 2eq of Me Grignard generates the Mg alkoxide of the bromohydrin which undergoes an internal cyclisation by loss of Br- and Mg++ to generate the epoxide.

Comment: So one one bromine is left behind  ?